# select record and start NSURLconnection and stop NSURLConnection when disconnect press

Tags: iphone, objective-c, connection, nsurlconnection, nsurl

i am really stuck with NSURLConnection

i have list of records : select on record press connection button and you can see the receive data from webservice

now i want to stop this connection when disconnect button pressed and back to record list view

now again i want to select other record -->connection-->i can see data-->disconnect

thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see question in your question :) It is definitely possible to implement it in such the way. Where is a problem?

Comment: i dont know how to stop connection, because when i want to click disconnect button the connection should be disconnect

Comment: and than i am again able to connect with other record to access data

Comment: Re stopping connection: see the answer. Re connecting again: just do it the same way as the fist time -- create new connection and call `start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is only with cancelling `NSURLConnection`, then you can try

```
[connection cancel];
```